# Spark 2.3.0 giving error : Provider org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat not a subtype

Tags: apache-spark

I am running Spark 2.3.0, and trying to load dataset from MySql (MariaDB) 
using : mysql-connector-java : version 6.0.6

```
  val dataSet:Dataset[Row] = spark
    .read
    .format("jdbc")
    .options(Map("url" -> jdbcUrl
                ,"user" -> username
                ,"password" -> password
                ,"dbtable" -> dataSourceTableName
                ,"driver" -> driver
                ))
    .load()
```

When I am running using spark-submit .. .. , I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider org.apache.spark.ml.source.libsvm.LibSVMFileFormat not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filterImpl(TraversableLike.scala:258)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:270)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
        at analytics.utils.QuantumDataSets$.loadDataSet(QuantumDataSets.scala:93)
        at analytics.utils.QuantumDataSets$.<init>(QuantumDataSets.scala:50)
        at analytics.utils.QuantumDataSets$.<clinit>(QuantumDataSets.scala)
        at analytics.utils.QuantumDataSets.main(QuantumDataSets.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Bhaskar, yes I solved the issue. issue was caused my version mismatch. It is a painful process to find and use the compatible versions of all dependencies. The one worked for me maynot work for you.. So keep trying by changing version

Comment: @RemisHaroon-رامز could you please elaborate on that? Which versions were it?
LibSVMFileFormat seems to be completely unrelated with mysql in any way

Comment: version mismatch for which dependancies?